# \hbox overflow, Friggeri fancy CV

Tags: spacing, friggeri-cv

I'm VERY new to LaTeX so the searches I have done have lead to zero progress in solving my problem. I've been playing around with the `entrylist` parameters on the `.cls` file to no avail. My essential problem is that after a certain amount of entries, LaTeX decides to put a big white space between my subcategory and my `entrylist`. The error I get is `\hbox overflow badness 10000`, and I understand this has to do with the amount of space not being large enough for the text, but I don't know how to change it.

I've spent a day going through the forum and I can't find an answer that helps. Please let me know what you need for you to help me.

Edit: I'm interested in an answer even though I found a work around, so here is the original code that I was editing:

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}    
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%    
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%    
\end{tabular*}    
}

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
   {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
   #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

I was playing around most often with the `#1&\parbox[t]{...}{%`  portion until I realized that the size was designating the horizontal parameters instead of vertical. Afterwards, I didn't know what those other numbers in the bottom of the code was, so I tinkered with those to no avail (as I'm sure you know). If you reference one of the answers, my work around was to brute force the situation by making a call for a new entry list for every entry so the entries are small enough for the parameters set until I found some other solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  The best would be you show us the minimal, compilable code you tried to solve your problem.  Then we can see were the problem is and help you ...Search on meta.tex if you do not know what a MWE, a minimal working example is ...

Comment: Even with your edit it is not clear wat you are asking Can you please  add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the user that posed the question and found a way to brute force an answer to this. I just made a new `\begin{entrylist}` for every entry. This method is not elegant, but it works because each entry is small enough for the `entrylist` parameters in the `.cls`.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).